# how to get hidden element value in javascript

Tags: javascript

how to get hidden element value in javascript

Comment: No, but SO is indexed by Google. People who ask the same question in the future will end up here, rather than at expert-sexchange, and isn't that much better?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

using the following document function

```
document.getElementById("elementId").value;
```

elementId-> id defined for the hidden element

Answer (score 5):

If the element has an id attribute and if it has a value attribute then you can use value property

```
document.getElementById( "hidElem" ).value;
```

for a hidden input element like

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidElem" />
```

otherwise you can use `textContent` property

```
document.getElementById( "hidElem" ).textContent;
```

for a hidden div element like

```
<div style="display: none;" id="hidElem">value of hidden element</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Putting ids on all your elements is overkill in my opinion. You can access them by their name attribute - all you need is a reference to the form object.

```
<form id="blah">
    <input type="hidden" name="inputOne" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="inputTwo" value="2" />
</form>


var formObj = document.getElementById('blah');
alert("Input one value: " + formObj.inputOne.value);
alert("Input two value: " + formObj.inputTwo.value);
```

This applies to all types of form input.